# Can't preload data from Data sqlite to my core data

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to preload a sqlite database to my core data sqlite.  I got first the sqlite from the simulator and then I filled some data in.

The problem is that I can not get data from the filled .sqlite in my root Directory to the coreData .sqlite(this file is store in the simulator)

I have tried with the apple example [CoreDataBooks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) but I does not work.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyData.sqlite"];


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
        NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyData" withExtension:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStoreURL) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL toURL:storeURL error:NULL];
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];

    NSError *error;
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Are you sure that MyData.sqlite is added to your target, so that it is copied into the app bundle? Is `defaultStoreURL` nil or not? Does `copyItemAtURL:...` return YES or NO? If NO, what is the error?

Comment: Sorry, I forget all that information. wait a second

Comment: And again, Martin R is asking just the right questions... :)

Comment: You were right.. I have copied the file but I did not add it to he target.. Now is working

Comment: @RoxeeMan: Glad to hear that. I have added my comment as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the "Target Membership" checkbox for the MyData.sqlite file,
otherwise it will not be copied into the application bundle.